# Expand pandas dataframe by categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, expansion

I am trying to expand dataframe by creating more columns specific to a value in one categorical column. My dataframe looks like this:

[image: Sample data]

Based on the value of the column `cluster`, I would like to create a new dataframe which should be like this :

```
var1_clus0 , var1_clus1, ... var3_clus2
```

I have a huge dataset so, I am trying to do this in a nested for loop which works fine for the 1st value of cluster column and all other have NaN.

Below is my script:

```
data_trans = pd.DataFrame()

for i in np.arange(0, len(varlist),1):
    for j in np.arange(0,6,1):
        data_trans[str(varlist[i]) + str("_clus_") + str(j)] = data[(data.segment_hc_print == j)][varlist[i]]
```

The code works without any error and generates the column as desired. But it parses only the first value of categorical column and puts them in a new column in new dataframe. For all other categorical values, it generates NAN. 
What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this ?

[image: Sample output]

Given the example dataset I gave, following is the desired output:
[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzeyh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 2D data set and varX and clusX may have multiple matches, you have to decide what you want to do with those matches?  I assume you want to add them up.  If so, you're looking at either a dataframe with a header row and a single data row, or just a series with the index being your varX_clusX.

The following code will do it:

```
# Setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var1'      : np.random.randint(0, 1000000, 1000000),
    'var2'      : np.random.randint(0, 1000000, 1000000),
    'var3'      : np.random.randint(0, 1000000, 1000000),
    'cluster'   : np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000000) 
    })

# Processing

# Setup the cluster column for string formatting.
df['cluster'] = 'clus' + df['cluster'].apply(str)

# Un-pivot the cluster column (I'm sure there's a better term)
df = df.set_index('cluster').stack().reset_index()

# Group by the unique combination of cluster / var and sum the values.
# This will generate a column named 0 - which I changed to 'values' just for readability.
df = df.groupby(['cluster','level_1']).sum().reset_index().rename(columns = {0 : 'values'})

# Create the formatted header you're looking for
df['piv'] = df['level_1'] + '_' + df['cluster']

# Final pivot to get the values to align with the the new headers
df = df.pivot(columns = 'piv', values = 'values').sum()
```

Timed this on my machine - roughly 1s for a million records.  Not sure how fast you need it.

If you don't want to add all the values and there's an arbitrary index, you can simplify:

```
df['cluster'] = 'clus' + df['cluster'].apply(str)

df = df.set_index('cluster').stack().reset_index()

df['piv'] = df['level_1'] + '_' + df['cluster']

df = df.pivot(columns = 'piv', values = 0).fillna(0)
```

This will give you a dataframe the length of your initial dataset x the number of variables and a ton of zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is not exactly what i am looking for. Var_x is simply a numeric variable and there may be hundreds of such var_x in the dataframe. Clus_x is a categorical variable with very few class labels , say 0 - 10 max. Each row has hundreds of Var_x and one cluster label (Say 0). What I want is to eliminate the need of cluster variable. So, instead of having 50 variables with 5 classes each, I would like to build 250 variables (var_x clus_x). Each of these 250 variables should contain the cross section of var_x and clus_x.

Comment: @ashutosh karna - I provided two options, I thought one would do it, but if not, you need to post your expected output, otherwise we can only make our best guess.

Comment: I think, I did not provide clear details of what I desire in my output. Sorry for that I just edited the question with the sample data and how the output should look like. The python script I wrote should work (I feel so) but this works only for the first column and rest all are returned as NAN.

Comment: What do you want to happen with multiple variable / cluster matches?